# Sphinx search infix and exact words in different fields

Tags: full-text-search, search-engine, sphinx

I'm using sphinx as search engine and I need to be able to do a search in different fields but using infix for one of the fields and exact word matches for another.

Simple example:

My source has for field_1 the value *"abcdef"* and for field_2 the value *"12345"*, what I need to accomplish is to be able to search by infix in field_1 and exact word in field_2. So a search like *"cde 12345"* would return the doc I mentioned.

Before when using sphinx v2.0.4 I was able to obtain these results just by defining infix_fields/prefix_fields on my index but now that I'm using v2.2.9 with the new dict=keywords mode and infix_fields are deprecated.

My index definition:

```
index my_index : my_base_index
{
    source = my_src
    path = /path/to/my_index
    min_word_len = 1
    min_infix_len = 3
}
```

I've tried so far to use extended query syntax in the following way:

```
$cl = new SphinxClient();
$q = (@(field_1) *cde* *12345*) | (@(field_2) cde 12345)
$result = $cl->Query($q, 'my_index');
```

This doesn't work because for each field, sphinx is doing an AND search and one of the words is not in the specified field, "12345" is not a match on field_1 and "cde" is not a match in field_2. Also I don't want to do an OR search, but need the both words to match.

Is there a way to accomplish what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a bit tricky, but can do

```
$q = "((@field_1 *cde*) | (@field_2 cde)) ((@field_1 *12345*) | (@field_2 12345))"
```

(dont need the brackets around the field name in the @syntax - if just one field, so removed them for brevity)

Comment: Hi Barry, thanks for your answer. Got any idea how this would behave about field weights? The documentation suggests the use of 2 separate indexes and SetIndexWeights() http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-min-prefix-len. Would this approach be also valid for two distinct indexes with distinct fields?

Comment: Multiple indexes wont help, have the same problem. Wont get a match, if one word is one index, and the other is in the other index.